# How To Deal With spaces in an MVC4 asp.net App (without c#)

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-declarative-helpers

I'm having trouble wrestling with inserting spaces in commas in a foreach loop.  Is there a better way to do this?  It bother

```
@{ var multipleSpeakerSeparator = " "; }
@foreach (var speaker in session.SpeakersList)
{
     @multipleSpeakerSeparator <a href="@(speaker.SpeakerLocalUrl)"> 
     @speaker.UserFirstName @speaker.UserLastName </a>multipleSpeakerSeparator = ",";
}
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS and add the padding that way? Seems cleaner if you really want those spaces.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get CSS to add commas to all but the last one on the list?

Comment: As far as CSS goes, it's not hard at all.  Just apply rules on the `::after` pseudo-element. Namely, set the `content` property to `", "`.  Enclose the whole list in some element, and tell `:last-child::after` that its content is `""`.  It's compatibility you have to worry about with that, though; IE 7 and 8 don't seem to understand pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use String.Join:

```
String.Join(",", session.SpeakersList.Select(i => "<a href=" + 
               i.SpeakerLocalUrl + ">..</a>");
```

I don't know if you can use @ syntax within String.Join, and how it would work, and how that would work with String.Join.  Otherwise, using string concatenation as shown above would work.

If you are trying to inject a space, a space literal should render appropriately.  I'm surprised it does not.  Anyway, using the foreach approach, you should be able to do `@<text> </text>`, and could conditionally do:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < session.SpeakersList.Count; i++)
{
     @{ 
       if (i > 0) { <text> </text> }
     }

     <a href="@(speaker.SpeakerLocalUrl)"> 
     @speaker.UserFirstName @speaker.UserLastName </a>multipleSpeakerSeparator = ",";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Is there no way to get literals to render? that is, something right in line with the markup to add the space?

Comment: Yes, I attached an updated example above.  I think that this would work; it should be possible to do `@<text> </text>` for a literal rendering.  Are spaces not rendering without using a variable to do that?